# were "the cylindrical wooden fastenings" horizontal or vertical?what does "wrenching asunder" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

were "the cylindrical wooden fastenings" horizontal or vertical? how can i imagine it?
what does "wrenching asunder" mean?

> (...)The parts broken were at least five feet removed from Slade, who
> had his back to the screen; but even if he had intended to tear it
> down by a cleverly devised sideward motion, it would have been
> necessary to fasten it on the opposite side. As it was, the screen
> stood quite unattached, and **the grain of the wood being parallel to
> the axis of the cylindrical wooden fastenings**, the **wrenching asunder**
> could only be accomplished by a force acting longitudinally to the
> part in question.

[From Transcendental Physics](https://books.google.de/books?id=UKBcTo7N3XYC&pg=PA34&lpg=PA34&dq=wrenching%20asunder&source=bl&ots=JSjA1fzP5-&sig=ACfU3U1bEs8FY132kuVlC9JPV4yoEBbVgw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUtdGInL7qAhUPHcAKHTQEAiwQ6AEwAnoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=wrenching%20asunder&f=false)

Comment: It does not say. "Wrenching asunder" means "ripping apart".

Comment: Did Zollner know Conan Doyle, I wonder?

Comment: Do you understand what "the grain of the wood" is? Have you looked that up?

Answer (score 1):

"Asunder" is defined as "apart". Wrenching, or tearing asunder means to tear into two separate pieces. Those words alone do not denote any direction of tearing - they could be torn horizontally, vertically, or diagonally.

The word in your extended quotation that indicates the two pieces were torn apart *horizontally* is "**longitudinally**", which means *in the direction of the **length***. This means the fastenings must have been horizontal. Were it torn top to bottom, this would be in the direction of the object's *height*.

The context helps. The kind of 'screen' it is talking about is evidently a free-standing *[folding screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folding_screen)*. These are commonly used to divide rooms or give privacy. The previous page in your book talks about this screen being around a bed, and it moving with the bed. The joints on which these screens fold are the "cylindrical wooden fastenings" referred to, and could be described as upright poles. It says that the grain of the wood must be *parallel* to these. If the grain of the wood also ran vertically that would mean it could be torn apart *horizontally*.

Comment: I cannot understand where you get that conclusion from (though I confess that I cannot form a mental picture of what the passage is describing). I agree that _longitudinally_ means "in the direction of the length". You seem to be concluding that that means that it cannot be "in the direction of height", and I find that conclusion unwarranted. Also, I cannot recall ever having seen "latitudinally" used as a contrast to "logintudinally" in this sense. I would expect "crosswise" or some such.

Comment: @ColinFine I've removed the reference to 'latitudinally', you're right it isn't used the same way as longitudinally. I've also added some further context.